# Spring Restdocs response payload contains optional empty list of objects

Tags: java, spring, spring-restdocs

My JSON response payload looks like this:

```
{
  "count": 2,
  "items": [
    {
      "k1": "v1",
      "k2": []
    },
    {
      "k1": "v2",
      "k2": [
        {
          "name": "joe"
        },
        {
          "name": "alice"
        }
      ]
    }
  ]
}
```

When I wrote Restdocs as bellow, I got an error complaining that `items[].k2 = []` is not documented.

```java
responseFields(
  fieldWithPath("count").description("..."),
  fieldWithPath("items[].k1").description("..."),
  fieldWithPath("items[].k2[].name").description("...")
)
```

I tried to write `fieldWithPath("items[].k2[].name").description("...").optional()`, but it didn't do anything.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a bug in Spring REST Docs. Thanks for bringing it to my attention.  Documenting `items[].k2[].name` should be sufficient for `items[].k2` to be considered to be documented as it has no undocumented content.  I have opened [this issue](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-restdocs/issues/626) so REST Docs' behaviour can be fixed.

Marking a field as optional tells REST Docs that the test should still pass if the field is not present. It has no effect on whether or not the field needs to be documented. This is why marking the field as `optional` has not worked around the problem.

You could work around the problem by explicitly documenting `items[].k2`:

```
fieldWithPath("items[].k2").description("...")
```

Alternatively, if you don't want an entry in your documentation for this field, you could tell REST Docs to ignore it:

```
fieldWithPath("items[].k2").ignored()
```